# Select 2 newest records from inner join table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to obtain the 2 newest records to graph the results.

I need to obtain the "Company Name", "First Date" and "Local Storage Percent" for the newest and second newest (previous) records. **The problem is that the newest date is showing the percent from the second newest (previous) record which also belongs to the second newest date.**

**USERS TABLE**

```
| id | company_name | usr_active | datto_host |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
| 1  | Company A    |    1       | companyA   |
| 2  | Company B    |    1       | companyB   |
| 3  | Company C    |    1       | companyC   |
```

**DATTO Table**

```
| id | device_model | date_recorded | local_storage_percent |   host   |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+----------+
| 106| ModelA       |   2023-03-23  |     95%               | companyA | 
| 108| ModelA       |   2023-03-22  |     83%               | companyA |
| 111| ModelC       |   2023-03-23  |     90%               | companyC |
```

**The query:**

```
select datto.device_model,  users.company_name, max(date_recorded) as first_date, max(datto.local_storage_percent) as local_storage_percent_current,
   substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(date_recorded order by date_recorded desc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as second_date,
   substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(local_storage_percent order by local_storage_percent desc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as local_storage_percent_previous from datto inner join users on datto.host = users.datto_host  where users.usractive = '1' group by users.company_name;
```

**The result**

```
| device_model | company_name | first_date | local_storage_percent_current | second_date | local_storage_percent_previous |
+--------------+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| ModelA       |   Company A  | 2023-03-23 |             83%               | 2023-03-22  |           83%                  |
```

**What I'm expecting:**

```
| device_model | company_name | first_date | local_storage_percent_current | second_date | local_storage_percent_previous |
+--------------+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| ModelA       |   Company A  | 2023-03-23 |             95%               | 2023-03-22  |           83%                  |
```

The **local_storage_percent_current** from the newest date is actually the same as the second date.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: Just had to remove max from max(datto.local_storage_percent). Hope this will help someone!